# How i can do a onclick for elements with editable attribute inside a iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to start a function by click on a element inside a iframe (ID:#iframe), which has the "contenteditable" attribute.

For inpage-my code works fine, but it doesn't work with the iframe.

What do I have to change that this code works with a iframe too?

```
$(document).on('click','[contenteditable]',function(e) { ... })
```

Thanks for helping and explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `contents()` of jquery function

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').find('[contenteditable]').on('click',function(e) { ... })
```

Comment: It seems, that on a single click, this fired twice - what can it caused?

Comment: How many contenteditable elements are present in targeted iFrame?

Comment: @RahulRaut a lot - unknown but much

Comment: Double fire not possible..give some working fiddle.i will resolve your problem.or check you define the function in you html one or more time

Comment: @Greg   You can add id on the contenteditable element in html, then attach click event on that id. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: yes, thats a way, i decide to redesign my code, so the problem is solved ;-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("iframe").load(function(){
     $(this).contents().find('body').find('#id-contenteditable').on("click", function(){
       /* your code goes here*/
    });
  });
});
```

On document ready and on iframe loading is complete, find the contenteditable attribute and bind the click event on the particular element.